# Excel Power Pivot aggrating data through a many to 1 then 1 to many relationsips

Tags: excel, relationship, one-to-many, powerpivot

I have 2 large tables in power pivot and I am trying to reconcile stockpile build grades to crushed stockpile grades.  Please see example.  I can create pivot table that contains the crushed grades but I am unable to find the right way to bring the stockpile grades though for the reconciliation high lighted in green in the attached example.

Thanks for any help or direction on where to look[image: simplitied example of what I am attempting]

Comment: Do you have lookup tables for date, crusher, source stockpiles, destination stockpiles and elements?

Comment: Yes I can create the look up table for the crusher, dates etc.  But was going to leave most of that for the pivot table so the user can just select the crusher they are interested in and the element using slices.  Thanks for look at this

Comment: You're welcome. Go ahead and create your tables for the unique dates and unique crushers. Give each table a key/ID column also. I will post more instructions in the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query, create your lookup tables.

1) unique crushers, ID
2) Dates, ID

Here is a function to create a dates table, if you need one.  After you invoke the function to get the column of dates, add another column for the ID.

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PQ Create a Dates Table, returning a single column of dates.  

    Inputs:
    Start Date    | Enter the year as yyyy, month as mm, day as dd
    End Date      | Enter the year as yyyy, month as mm, day as dd
    Increments    | One row will be returned per increment. 

    Author:  Jenn Ratten

    Edits:   
    07/16/18      | Modified query copied from the internet.
    10/01/19      | Converted to a function.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

let

    fDatesTable = (StartYear as number, StartMonth as number, StartDay as number, EndYear as number, EndMonth as number, EndDay as number, IncrementDays as number, IncrementHours as number, IncrementMin as number, IncrementSec as number) as table =>

    let    

        StartDate = #date(StartYear,StartMonth,StartDay),
        EndDate = #date(EndYear,EndMonth,EndDay),
        Increments = #duration(IncrementDays,IncrementHours,IncrementMin,IncrementSec),
        DatesTable = Table.FromColumns({List.Dates(StartDate, Number.From(EndDate) - Number.From(StartDate), Increments)}, type table[Date]),
        ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(DatesTable,{{"Date", type date}})

    in

        ChangeType
in

    fDatesTable
```

Load all of the tables to the data model.

Go to Power Pivot, diagram view, and create your relationships.

- Lookup Crusher to data tables 1 and 2
- Lookup Date to data tables 1 and 2

Go to Data View on data tables 1 and 2, add 2 new columns for the lookup IDs.  You can specify the column header and the formula at one time by clicking in first cell and using this syntax, then either press enter or click the check mark in the formula bar.

```
Dates Lookup ID:=RELATED(lookup_dates[ID])
Crusher Lookup ID:=RELATED(lookup_crusher[ID])
```

*Optional, but a good practice....*
Right-click the new fields you just created and select "hide from client tools".  Also hide the date and crusher fields on both data tables, and the ID field on both lookup tables.  When you are creating pivots to summarize data from more than one table, the text fields that you place on your pivot table should be the fields that are shared (aka the lookup tables).  This helps to minimize pivots in which the grand totals don't match the sum that you actually see on the table.  If you hide the fields, it reminds you of that.  There are exceptions of course, but this is a good rule of thumb.

Now create measures to sum the tons and any other math calculations you'd like.  With the measures, start simple and let the pivot do the slicing.  Put the measures in the values section of the pivot table.

```
Sum of Source Tons:=sum(Table1[Tons])

Sum of Destination Tons:=sum(Table2[Tons])
```